# Split into multiple rows in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table looks like -  [image]

And I want to achieve like this -  [image]

Please help the SQL

Comment: Column names are static or dynamic?

Comment: In Oracle you can use UNPIVOT but I have no idea if it is available in SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

Use `apply`:

```
select t.collegeid, t.deptid, t.empid, v.yr, v.mnth, v.act, v.pred
from t outer apply
     (values (act201701, pred201701, 2017, 1),
             (act201702, pred201702, 2017, 2),
             (act201703, pred201703, 2017, 3),
     ) v(act, pred, yr, mnth);
```

You can also do the same thing using `unpivot`.  However, `apply` implements lateral joins, which are much more powerful than merely unpivoting data.

Answer (score 1):

Provided the Column Names are static, you probably may use the UNION SELECT query, something like the following:

```
Select CollegeID, DeptID, EmpID, "2017" As Y, "1" As Mnth, [Act201701] As Act, [Pred201701] As Pred from [SomeTable]
UNION
Select CollegeID, DeptID, EmpID, "2017" As Y, "2" As Mnth, [Act201702] As Act, [Pred201702] As Pred from [SomeTable]
UNION
Select CollegeID, DeptID, EmpID, "2017" As Y, "3" As Mnth, [Act201703] As Act, [Pred201703] As Pred from [SomeTable]
```

where `SomeTable` is your Table Name.

Answer (score 0):

replace the table name and try

```
insert into yourTableName (CollegeID, DeptID, EmpID, Yr, Mnth, Act, Pred) values (234, 34, 4, 2017, 1, 6131.86, 6131.82)
```